# Как растянуть окно на весь экран (и перекрыть панель задач)?

Tags: java, swing, gui, awt

Мне нужно убрать из окна рамку  и растянуть его так, чтобы панель задач осталась под ним. как это можно сделать и еще как зделать блокирование нажатий клавиш на клавиатуре?

Comment: Установите событие максимизировать.

Comment: как зделать блокирование нажатий клавиш на клавиатуре?